# Figure out why WinDBG is in "BUSY" state?

Tags: windbg

I'm unable to figure out why WinDBG is in a BUSY state:

[image]

Is there a way to find a description?

Comment: probably downloading symbols try disconnecting internet for a few minutes and hitting ctrl+break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to find the exact reason why WinDbg is busy, but you can verify what the last event it was responding to, by using '.lastevent'. However, for your particular case, it is busy looking for symbols and source code for kernel32!CreateFileW. If you have an extension registered for events you would receive change symbol state

[IDebugEventCallbacksWide::ChangeSymbolState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/nf-dbgeng-idebugeventcallbackswide-changesymbolstate)

```
DEBUG_CSS_LOADS The engine has loaded some module symbols.
DEBUG_CSS_UNLOADS   The engine has unloaded some module symbols.
DEBUG_CSS_SCOPE The current symbol scope has changed.
DEBUG_CSS_PATHS The executable image, source , or symbol search paths have changed.
DEBUG_CSS_SYMBOL_OPTIONS    The symbol options have changed.
DEBUG_CSS_TYPE_OPTIONS  The type options have changed.
```

Also check this:

[IDebugEventCallbacksWide::ChangeEngineState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/nf-dbgeng-idebugeventcallbackswide-changeenginestate)

Those events are:

```
DEBUG_CES_CURRENT_THREAD    The current thread has changed, which implies that the current target and current process might also have changed.
DEBUG_CES_EFFECTIVE_PROCESSOR   The effective processor has changed.
DEBUG_CES_BREAKPOINTS   One or more breakpoints have changed.
DEBUG_CES_CODE_LEVEL    The code interpretation level has changed.
DEBUG_CES_EXECUTION_STATUS  The execution status has changed.
DEBUG_CES_ENGINE_OPTIONS    The engine options have changed.
DEBUG_CES_LOG_FILE  The log file has been opened or closed.
DEBUG_CES_RADIX The default radix has changed.
DEBUG_CES_EVENT_FILTERS The event filters have changed.
DEBUG_CES_PROCESS_OPTIONS   The process options for the current process have changed.
DEBUG_CES_EXTENSIONS    Extension DLLs have been loaded or unloaded. (For more information, see Loading Debugger Extension DLLs.)
DEBUG_CES_SYSTEMS   A target has been added or removed.
DEBUG_CES_ASSEMBLY_OPTIONS  The assemble options have changed.
DEBUG_CES_EXPRESSION_SYNTAX The default expression syntax has changed.
DEBUG_CES_TEXT_REPLACEMENTS Text replacements have changed.
```